# Fragments at java

Tags: java, android

I'm new to fragments, and I have a question about it. I have a task "on the first fragment there should be a list of cities, on the second fragment - the weather forecast and your checkboxes." I don’t understand a bit how to place elements in "activity_main.xml" , because all TextView, CheckBoxes and others things shifts to the upper left corner.(here is a link to the code if you are interested in looking https://cloud.mail.ru/public/74cr/8VWjDPx37 ) Please explain me, how to get a result, thanks!

Comment: I assume you are using constraint layout. If so please read about it and hot to set constraints.Or even if you are using any other layout. Read about it first.

Comment: You attached image link is not valid.